# How to give relative path to Runtime.exec

Tags: java, process, exec, embedded-resource, runtime.exec

Hello all I am trying to run `help file(.chm)` from `netbeans` directory with the help of this code

```
Process proc=   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hh.exe src/MOVECG_Pro.chm");
```

but problem arises when I try to run outside `netbeans` because inside jar `src` folder is not there. Kindly help me how to code it properly

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: i have read and implemented the recommendations but can't find the solution because either i get the exception as `file not found` or `can not open the file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed your `chm` file inside your source code directory. Clearly that directory is not there when you run the JAR. I guess you want to have a standalone JAR which contains the help file bundled within it.

Since `exec` delegates to the native platform to interpret the command string as something it can start a subprocess with, you can imagine that there will be trouble with transparently accessing a file buried inside the JAR archive.

So either provide the help file separately, or write code which will *extract* the help file from the JAR at runtime. Then pass its location to `hh.exe`.

Let me also make a general statement: since you are writing a Java program here, which is supposed to be platform-independent, your approach with a Windows-specific help file isn't exactly by the book.

Comment: Thank you very much @Marko. I have implemented your way!